# Twitter Bootstrap column and Google Maps not working together

Tags: css, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a silly css problem but I can't seem to solve it. I'm inserting a google map into a 12 size twitter bootstrap column:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" style="height:50%;">
   <div id="map-canvas" style="position:static !important;height:50%  !important;"></div>
</div>
```

I end up with the map loading but it doesn't take up any space/height:

[image]

I've tried adding a height to the map. I've tried adding a height to the column and nothing seems to work. Someone show me the light here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set a specific pixel height for `#mapCanvas`..

or make sure the mapCanvas containers (html,body) have a height..

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#map-canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 50%;
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/118448